# Run i3 commands from the command line

Tags: i3, tiling-wm

I am writing a script which allows me to start my report writing setup (pdf viewer, vim, terminal) automatically. For this, I want to start okular, set the split mode of the terminal to vertical and start another terminal. The problem is that the i3 command `split h` does not what it does in i3.

Is there a way to run those i3 commands in the terminal?

Best,
Alexander Schoch

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can execute i3 commands with `i3-msg`. For `split h` use `i3-msg split h`.  For other commands see the [i3 User’s Guide, List of commands](https://i3wm.org/docs/userguide.html#list_of_commands).

Comment: Thank you. I really couldn‘t find that information online...